# What is the Big O of a For Loop, Iterated Square Root Times?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, computer-science

I am trying to find the Big O for this code fragment:

```
for (j = 0; j < Math.pow(n,0.5); j++ ) {
 /* some constant operations */
}
```

Since the loop runs for √n times, I am assuming this for-loop is O(√n). However, I read online that √n = O(logn).

So is this for loop O(√n) or O(logn)?

Thanks!

Comment: `√n = O(logn)` is just stupid. Where did you read this? Obviously the loop will run `O(sqrt(n))` times.

Comment: Where did you read that √n = O(logn)? Certainly, O(√n) != O(logn) since √n != log(n). Perhaps what was meant was that a certain algorithm to compute √n was O(logn)

Comment: Please provide the link which says O(√n)=O(logn). In fact O(√n) > O(logn) for large n.

Comment: So this for-loop just has O(√n)?

Comment: Yes, assuming `j - 0` is a typo (should be `j = 0`)

Comment: And assuming `n` doesn't change in the middle of the loop :) :)

Comment: If `n` isn't modified inside the loop, `n^0.5 = sqrt(n)`, but like a log is the inverse of exponential, it would be O(log(n)) I guess.

Comment: @carexcer `n^0.5 = sqrt(n)` is not related to logs at all.  How do you conclude that?

Comment: @TedHopp: "O(√n) != O(logn) since √n != log(n)" Now that argumentation is just as wrong as the original statement...

Comment: @Matt: "In fact O(√n) > O(logn) for large n" That statement doesn't make sense. O-notation says something about functions, not values.

Comment: @NiklasB. You're absolutely correct; I'm overloading `>` in that statement ;)

Comment: @Matt: What I meant was the "for large n" part. If n was not a free variable, we couldn't even apply the O symbol. Comparing two sets (cause `O(...)` really just is a set of functions) using > is also not well-defined, you're right about that.

Comment: @NiklasB. - Yeah, I was being sloppy. I should have said "...since |√n| / |log(n)| is not asymptotically bounded" (or something like that).

Comment: Oh, I think we all know what is meant when we say something like `O(n^2) > O(n)`.  Matt's point was clear when he said `O(√n) > O(log n)`, namely that the square-root part is the significant part, not the log.

Comment: @NiklasB. You're right there too; thanks for the reminder that we can have brevity without sacrificing precision.

Comment: @David: Sadly people use Landau notation incorrectly all the time and I conjecture that at least some of them really don't know better, so in my opinion regardless of whether it's clear what is meant, it's still better to stay precise if possible. I'm not implying a lack of understanding in this particular case. I'll stop being a smartass now, though :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One has to make several assumptions, but the time complexity of this loop appears to be O(√n). The assumptions are:

- the loop body executes in constant time regardless of the value of `j`.
- `j` is not modified in the loop body
- `n` is not modified in the loop body
- `Math.pow(n,0.5)` executes in constant time (probably true, but depends on the specific Java execution environment)

As a comment noted, this also assumes that the loop initialization is `j = 0` rather than `j - 0`.

Note that the loop would be much more efficient if it was rewritten:

```
double limit = Math.pow(n, 0.5);
for (j = 0; j < limit; j++ ) {
 /* some constant operations */
}
```

(This is a valid refactoring only if the body does not change `n`.)

Comment: Can Java not do this kind of optimization itself?!

Comment: I would expect it to optimize this at least if `n` is a local variable, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @NiklasB. Java cannot know that `Math.pow` will always return the same value, even if the arguments are the same (if that's what you were asking about).

Comment: @NiklasB. - It's asking a lot of the compiler. Not only would it have to be able to establish that `n` did not change values (declaring it `final` would help), but the compiler would also have to know that `Math.pow(n,0.5)` returns the same value every time it is called with the same arguments. I don't think the compiler has such a detailed model available of the entire standard API.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Why not? It knows exactly what `Math.pow` is doing

Comment: It won't optimise this if `n` is volatile.

Comment: @NiklasB. Note that `pow` delegates to a `native` method (at least in Oracle JDK 7), but even if it didn't, it's not possible.

Comment: @David: Sure, but in this case it's quite unlikely that it is declared as `volatile`...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: C++ compilers do this kind of stuff all the time. I would really think less of Java if it wouldn't at least JIT-optimize this situation, but I'm actuallly not finding any resources about it right now

Comment: @NiklasB. That's more of a functional programming language feature.

Comment: Yeah, everything would be better if the loop said `j * j < n` instead of `j < Math.pow(n, 0.5)`.  Let the integers be integers and the floating point numbers be floating point.

Comment: Aaaand you're all right, Oracle Java does *not* factor out the result of `Math.pow(n,0.5)` even if `n` is a local variable. Kinda lame though, since both gcj (the Java compiler) does it and g++ does it too for the `pow` function.

Comment: Yeah, it would be cool if Java had an `idempotent` keyword, that you could put on methods like `Math.pow` to tell the compiler that it can optimise out repeated calls with the same arguments.

Comment: @David: *j * j < n* would incur an integer multiply on each iteration; except for small *n*, it is advantageous to compute the integer square root once for all (unfortunately not available as such, must be emulated through floating-point *sqrt*).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cost of the `pow` operation to be `O(P(n))` for some function `P`, the global cost of the loop is `O(√n.P(n))`. If the `pow` call is taken out of the loop and performed only once, the cost is expressed as `O(√n+P(n))`.

In case `P(n)=1`, this gives respectively `O(√n)` and `O(√n)`.

In case `P(n)=log(n)`, this gives **`O(√n.log(n))`** and `O(√n)`.

[The lower order term of the sum is absorbed by the other.]

The assumption `P(n)=log(n)` could be valid in the context of arbitrary precision integers, where the representation of an integer `n` requires at least `O(log(n))` bits. But that makes sense for huge values of `n` only.